# Outlook on Mac - Links are slow

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mac, microsoft-outlook

Firstly, I'm not sure this is the right forum for this kind of question. Apologies if I'm wrong.

For work, I use the desktop app for Outlook emails on my Mac. I often get emails containing Jira links. When I click one of these links to open in my browser (chrome is already running), it takes around a minute to actually open a tab on Chrome.

My guess is it's "verifying" the link for safety but I can't be sure of that.

If my guess about verifying is correct, then, if it helps, anything from a specific email (jira@redacted.net) could be implicitly trusted meaning Id be fine turning off verification for those links.

Any advice?

Comment: Does the issue also exist on another browser?

Comment: I checked with Safari. I observed a delay